# Homomorphism $f: F_2 \rightarrow \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $f: F_2 \rightarrow \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ be a homomorphism that sends $a$ to $(1,0)$ and $b$ to $(0,1).$ 
>   a) Prove that there is only one such homomorphism. 
>   b) Compute $f(aba^{-1}b^{-1})$. 
>   c) Which elements of $F_2$ are in the $Ker(f)$? 
>   d) Use part (c) to explain why any conjugate of an element of $Ker(f)$ is also in $Ker(f)$.

**My attempt:** 
a)Pick an arbitrary element of the free group $F_2=<a,b>,$ say $a^{r_1}b^{s_1}a^{r_2}b^{s_2}...,$ then $f(a^{r_1}b^{s_1}a^{r_2}b^{s_2}...)=r_1f(a)+s_1f(b)+r_2f(a)+s_2f(b)+...=(r_1+r_2+...)f(a)+(s_1+s_2+...)f(b)$ 
 (by homomorphism property).
Let $(r_1+r_2+...)=2m+n, (s_1+s_2+...)=2k+l$, then $[r_1+r_2+...]_2=[n]_2,[s_1+s_2+...]_2=[l]_2$. Therfore, we have $$f(a^{r_1}b^{s_1}a^{r_2}b^{s_2}...)=nf(a)+lf(b)=(n,l).$$ 
b) $f(aba^{-1}b^{-1})=f(a)f(b)f(a^{-1})f(b^{-1})=(1,0)+(0,1)+(1,0)+(0,1)= (0,0).$ Here we used $f(a^{-1})=(f(a))^{-1}=f(a)$. 
c) Let $a^{r_1}b^{s_1}a^{r_2}b^{s_2}...$ be in the $Ker(f),$ then $f(a^{r_1}b^{s_1}a^{r_2}b^{s_2}...)=e.$, Then 
$\begin{cases}
(r_1+r_2+...)=[0]_2\\
(s_1+s_2+...)=[0]_2
\end{cases}.$
Therefore, if the above condition holds, the element is in the $Ker(f)$

I'm not sure if I got these parts right, I'm new to Abstract Algebra, so any comments would be appreciated. As for part d) I have no ideas how to start. We want to show that $f(ghg^{-1})=e$ for any $g \in F_2, h$ in subgroup of $G$, right?

Comment: For $F_n=\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ the free group and $f$ an homomorphism to an abelian group $G$ then $f = h \circ \phi$ with $\phi : F_n\to \Bbb{Z}^n, \phi(a_j) = e_j$ and $h$ an homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}^n \to G$.

Comment: Hint for (d): Let your $h\in\mathrm{ker}(f)$. Write both $g$ and $h$ as products of $a$ and $b$ and check if $ghg^{-1}$ satisfies the criterion to be in ker(f) from (c).

Comment: @EdwardH., I tried to rewrite $$  and $ℎ$ as products of $$ and $$, then $g = a^{m_1}b^{n_1}a^{m_2}b^{n_2}..., h = a^{r_1}b^{s_1}a^{r_2}b^{s_2}...,$ where $[r_1+r_2+...]_2=[0]_2, [s_1+s_2+...]_2=[0]_2.$ Therefore, using homomorphism properties, we get $f(ghg^{-1}) = f(a^{m_1}b^{n_1}a^{m_2}b^{n_2}...)f(a^{r_1}b^{s_1}a^{r_2}b^{s_2}...)(f(a^{m_1}b^{n_1}a^{m_2}b^{n_2}...))^{-1}.$ I don't know how to simplify this...

Comment: @EdwardH., I had an idea: since $h \in Ker(f), f(h)=e,$ so $f(ghg^{-1}) = f(a^{m_1}b^{n_1}a^{m_2}b^{n_2}...)e(f(a^{m_1}b^{n_1}a^{m_2}b^{n_2}...))^{-1}=e$, so $ghg^{-1} \in Ker(f).$ But how to prove that using part $(c)$?

Comment: That is indeed the correct way if you were not to use (c). To use (c) consider that $g^{-1}=\cdots b^{-n_2}a^{-m_2}b^{-n_1}a^{-m_1}$, then the question is whether $ghg^{-1}$ as a product of $a$s and $b$s has even sum of exponents in $a$ and $b$.